# Как автоматически раздать ключ при занесении значения в объект?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть такой код (подрезал для упрощения):

```js
let names = {
    0: 'name1',
    1: 'name2',
    2: 'name3'
};

class Element extends React.Component {

    ....
    
    handleAddElement = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            input:''
        });
        let result = this.input;
    }

    render () {
        let brand = this.props.brand;
        return (
        .... {names[brand]} ....
        );
    }
}

function App () {
    return (
            <div>
                <Element brand="0"/>
                <Element brand="1"/>
                <Element brand="2"/>
            </div>
    );
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы из handleAddElement результат инпута добавлялся в объект и у него автоматически ставился ключ. Также мне нужно, чтобы в функции App автоматически выставлялся ключ brand. Подскажите как реализовать.

Comment: Зачем вам обьект если у вас только индексы?

Comment: @RavenTheX на самом деле, действительно, зачем. Тогда первый вопрос снимается и остается второй, как выставлять ключ brand автоматически? По итогу мне как то надо при каждом добавлении в массив неймс добавлять вызов элемента с автоматически проставленным индексом brand.

Comment: @RavenTheX хотя вспомнил зачем мне нужен был объект. Чтобы перед добавлением делать проверку на повторяющиеся имена. Не знаю пока, можно ли такое сделать с обычным массивом.

Comment: Не очень понятно что такое "выставлять ключ", опишите что у вас есть на вход и что должно получится

Comment: @RavenTheX проверку на наличие в массиве нагуглил, первый вопрос действительно решен. Описываю процесс кода: из инпута добавляется имя в массив. Функция App вызывает Element со значениями массива, ссылаясь по индексу прописанному в brand. И вот мне нужна автоматическая генерация вызова Element в функции App. Надеюсь теперь понятно.

Comment: Вам это не подойдет https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html ?

Comment: @RavenTheX вроде бы оно, но пока встроить не могу, нужно время на разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы отрендерить массив вам нужен метод `map` https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html